# Advice on additional documents for UK family visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I applied for UK family visitor visa for my uncle and aunt who are Pakistani citizens and are over 70 years of age. My uncle is retired shopkeeper and has no pension. My aunt is/was a housewife. They live with their son and his wife and two children.  Their son is a school teacher and looks after them. They live in their own property.  They have no bank account of their own.

The documents I submitted were:

1 - sponsorship letter / UK 6 months bank statements / UK pension income documents / UK property ownership documents

2 - Letter written by son stating that he supports his parents financially along with 6 month bank statement (current account showing salary deposit. He does not have any significant savings) and national ID card.

3 - Copy of property ownership document which is in local language. A attested English translation was submitted.

4 - Additional information stated that uncle/aunt have total of 8 adult children and lots of grandchildren to whom they will return to after they 6-8 week stay.

They were refused visa and the refusal letter stated:

**I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraphs 4.2 (a) (c) of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for visitors because:

- Whilst it is acknowledged that you sponsor states they will pay for your travel/maintenance in the UK and you have submitted financial documents to confirm their funds, I have to be satisfied about the circumstances in which you live in Pakistan.

  - I recognise that family visits are important. However, under the UK immigration rules, you must show that you qualify for a visa by explaining your own circumstances and the plans you have for your visit. I must assess the information you have provided about yourself separately from your sponsor's part of your application.
  - The starting point for the assessment of any visa application is the information contained in the visa application form and supporting documents.
  - You have stated in your visa application form that you are retired and have no savings, properties or other income and state to be dependent on your Pakistan based son. Whilst it is noted you have submitted a letter of support from him with a photocopied ID card and bank statement, there is no documentation to support the salary payments into the account.  Furthermore, whilst the ID card is noted, this like the other photocopied documents is not a verified copy and as such changes could have been made in the copying process. This leads me to doubt they reflect his circumstances and as such your own.
  - Notwithstanding this to support your own circumstances you have submitted a land deed but no other documentation in your name or your spouse's to confirm the social and economic circumstances in which you live in Pakistan. In view of these concerns I consider that you have not provided a satisfactory basis upon which I might assess your current stated circumstances.
  - In view of this, I am not satisfied you have shown that, on balance of probabilities, your ties to Pakistan are sufficient to provide you with a genuine incentive to leave the UK at the end of your proposed visit. I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor or intend to leave the UK at the end of your visit.**

*We HAD submitted property ownership document which was attested and translated into English (although refusal states it was land registry document. The additional information stated clearly the supporting documents being submitted).*

I intend to apply again and submit the original supporting documents along with:
 - **Son's payslips** (we had already submitted his bank statements)
- **Second son's letter of support / bank statements / payslips**
- **Family registration certificate** that links all the grown up children's National Identity cards into one document.

**I wanted advise on who best to get all the photocopied documents verified by - should it be a notary public or someone else?**

*How else can they show their ties to Pakistan and intention to return?*

Any advise would be greatly appreciated asap.

Many thanks

PK

Comment: Hello Gayot. My query is more specifically about what additional documents can be submitted to show ties to home country apart from what I have suggested towards end of my post. My second query was about the best method of getting photocopied documents verified. Thanks

Comment: Dear Gayot. I am unclear what you mean by your comments. I responded initially to clarify that my question was not a complete duplicate of a previous post. And one of my queries was regarding the best way to get the documents certified - as it seems there several options in Pakistan.

Comment: The question you have linked it to and said is duplicate is about bank statements. My queries are not related to bank statements. I cannot see the "reopen" button but have tried to edit my query

Comment: While it might not be a duplicate, I do not think this visa application stand much of a chance. Not having a bank account is just one problem. Not having a regular income, not having strong ties and not having children in the UK to visit make their application unlikely to be granted, each in their own right.